# Swipe to delete using android studio and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swipe-gesture

I want to make the "swipe to delete" in my project. but whenever I swipe to delete it, it does not delete in firebase and it makes the same data appear again in the app because in does not delete in firebase. How do I fix this?

This is my code.

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

    switch (direction){
        case ItemTouchHelper.LEFT:
            viewApplicationDataList.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

            dbApplication.child("LIST OF FORM").child(String.valueOf(position)).equals(null);

            break;
    }
    if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
        Toast.makeText(ViewApplicationActivity.this,"Deleting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

[image: Firebase picture]

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/),  then I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) might help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the "remove" function in order to remove a value.
In your code, what you actually do is write another data to your firebase
So instead of

```
dbApplication.child("LIST OF FORM").child(String.valueOf(position)).equals(null);
```

do

```
dbApplication.child("LIST OF FORM").child(String.valueOf(position)).removeValue();
```

That way you will remove that value from your database.

***edit***

Because you haven't response to my question in the comment I will explain it in general on how to remove a value from firebase.

When you access the child note of "LIST OF FORM" you have to access the correct child node ( aka from your picture, that firebase id ) and then use the removeValue() function.
meaning

```
dbApplication.child("LIST OF FORM").child(*uniqueID*).removeValue()
```

*uniqueID = the id that was generated automatically by the firebase when you entered that value OR the one you used
So for you to understand it even more to delete what ever you posted in your screenshot the query need to be like this

```
dbApplication.child("LIST OF FORM").child("-MbVVxjqTitBwuLo5DyL").removeValue();
```

Where the "-MbVVxjqTitBwuLo5DyL" is the child you want to remove.
if you not access that value anywhere in your code, you won't be able to remove that value from your database.

Comment: Tried your answer but it still does not delete in database

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of your firebase and how the collection looks like?
I simply used your code and replace it with the removeValue() funciton.
so if this doesn't work, meaning you don't have this value ( as in position )

Comment: Done! can click the "Firebase picture"

Comment: Based on that picture you have a unique Firebase value stored after the "LIST OF FORM", do you store it somewhere? in the position?
If you using this in the adapter the position usually store the position of the item in the array and not the actual value of the ID I mentioned.

Comment: yes, if that way it can be deleted. but i have multiple child, not only "-MbVVxjqTitBwuLo5DyL". if I use it, the only data that will be deleted is the data under "-MbVVxjqTitBwuLo5DyL".  "-MbVVxjqTitBwuLo5DyL" is one of child that is under "LIST OF FORM".  What if I wanted to delete random data under "LIST OF FORM" according to the position that I choose to swipe to delete?

Comment: You need to get that value in your code, if you using position you using a integer that represent the position of that item in the list you holding that data in BUT you can't use that value to delete the item from your database as you don't have a child with the value of position.
so what you need to do is to store the id of that item in a temp value and then delete it when the user wants to.

Comment: As I also commented on your new [question that you've since deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67859609): You will need to keep a mapping from the position that Android tells you to the `-MbW7PbQ_ytAndTheRestOfTheID` key that the node has in Firebase. So when you read the data from the database for the adapter, instead of just taking its value (that you display), also get the keys and keep them in a list/array and use that to look up the key of the clicked item.